# why does I'm seeing Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf') in my browser console for Angular application

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, angular10, pollyjs

When I'm running the application I'm seeing the below console error, in one of my angular application, and I didn't see any relevant code which causing the issue in the application.

I try to add console logs in all JS files and verifying values objects with es6 && operator in HTML pages to prevent this log error.

The below error is happening in the file polyfills-es5.js.

`

```
Error: 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')
    at HTMLDocument.gotTacEvent (0d90487350e8f20ecdd12f620df72322.js?conditionId0=4935604:2:312)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills-es5.js?2ee446b5f8a8f964a156:13:7853)
    at e.runTask (polyfills-es5.js?2ee446b5f8a8f964a156:13:2932)
    at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills-es5.js?2ee446b5f8a8f964a156:13:8985)
    at p (polyfills-es5.js?2ee446b5f8a8f964a156:44:734)
    at HTMLDocument.h (polyfills-es5.js?2ee446b5f8a8f964a156:44:1040)
    at sendEventToEngines (Bootstrap.js:480:96)
    at HTMLDocument.processClickEvent (Bootstrap.js:473:478)
gotTacEvent @ 0d90487350e8f20ecdd12f620df72322.js?conditionId0=4935604:2
t.invokeTask @ polyfills-es5.js?2ee446b5f8a8f964a156:13
e.runTask @ polyfills-es5.js?2ee446b5f8a8f964a156:13
e.invokeTask @ polyfills-es5.js?2ee446b5f8a8f964a156:13
p @ polyfills-es5.js?2ee446b5f8a8f964a156:44
h @ polyfills-es5.js?2ee446b5f8a8f964a156:44
sendEventToEngines @ Bootstrap.js:480
processClickEvent @ Bootstrap.js:473
```

`

[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGDkR.png)

[Actual error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wfDq.png)

Please help me to understand the reason for this error.

Thank you

Comment: Please include your code as text in your post, rather than an image. The image you posted does not have any reference to `indexOf`, so it's hard to tell what's going on, but seems like the object you are calling `indexOf` on doesn't exist.

Comment: hi @mykaf,     It is a polyfile which is very big to post here.

Comment: Well it sounds like it's not define when you try to call `indexOf()` on it

Comment: Am I allow to make changes in Polyfills-es5.js

Comment: It's more likely something you are passing to a function in that file.

Comment: Where possible post data and error messages  as text (formatted) rather than images for easier readability.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code within your “gotTacEvent” function for an indexOf() call. Whatever variable you are calling indexOf() on is not defined.

Say your function contains something like:

```
let index = myArray.indexOf(‘dog’)
```

If myArray is not defined, then you’ll get the error you’re seeing. You can fix it by doing an undefined check first.

```
if (myArray == null) return;
let index = myArray.indexOf(‘dog’)
```

Note the above null check will cover both cases when the variable is undefined and when it’s null. More info on why that is can be found [here](https://stackabuse.com/javascript-check-if-variable-is-a-undefined-or-null/).